How to display numbers with Portuguese formatting in a Streamlit dashboard?
I am building a Streamlit dashboard where the final audience speaks Portuguese. In Portuguese, the decimal and thousands separators are different from English:
Number: 1000.5
English format: 1,000.5
Portuguese format: 1.000,5
By default, Python and Streamlit use the English format, but I need to adapt the number formatting to follow the Portuguese style (using . for thousands and , for decimals).
What is the best way to achieve this in a Streamlit application? Are there any built-in functions or libraries I should use?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

You can use babel for internationalizing Python applications as follows:
import streamlit as st
from babel.numbers import format_decimal

number = 1000.5
formatted_number = format_decimal(number, locale='pt_BR')
st.write(formatted_number)

# Output
# 1.000,5

Easy and straightforward.

You should set your locale variable to get the output you want:
import streamlit as st

import locale

n = 1000.5
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_BR.utf8")
st.write(locale.format_string("%.2f", n, grouping=True))


Could replace special characters in strings:
value = 9024178.32
print(f"{value:_}".replace(".", ",").replace("_", "."))

which gives:  9.024.178,32
